# Resolution stuck at 800x600

Tags: windows-8.1, graphics-card

I just set up a new computer. I built it. AMD 7850k and then connected my old monitor. I'm using it right now to post this I had to connect it to my old computer. I'm using it at resolution of 1280x1024 but on the Win8.1 its only allowing me to go 800x600 why is this? I thought AMD 7850k graphics was superb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend reinstalling the graphics drivers.  You can try to install new graphics drivers by right clicking on Computer in the start menu and then clicking on properties.  Once there you can choose device manager.  Check your display adapters and try to update the drivers by right clicking on them and automatically searching.

I also would recommend doing windows updates.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Oh my gosh such a stupid thing I missed. I can't belive it. Reason i didnt think of it is cuz my hardware didnt come with any cd's. I'll search out online maybe amd 7850k apu drivers?

Comment: I'm sure a quick search for drivers will do.  I always recommend right clicking on the Display Adapter > Properties > Details Tab and changing the property to Hardware ID's, then proceed to search those Hardware ID's, normally plenty of results come up.